# Creating datatables from another server's database into php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

suppose i have a table in a database into another server and i want to create datatables into php fetching the data from another server's database. Guide me how to do that?

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve the above scenario.
You will have to make a remote connection to your database in your php script, either by using PDO or mysqli.
Once the remote connection is established, then you can work on your datatables just the way you would do with your local database.
Example:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=REMOTE-IP-ADDRESS;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password');
```

**OR**

```
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('REMOTE-IP-ADDRESS', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
```

Or you can also specify the remote domain.

Comment: will it work with above connection snippet?

Comment: Yes it will just set your own IP/hostname and user,password and database name

Comment: alright i will try this.

Comment: Sure, share the results if you encounter any problems.